# The correct and clean way to not render a child template in a parent template in Ember

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I am overhauling an old project to use ember with firebase for persisting data. It is a restaurant site, I added authentication and I am allowing admin users to add and delete menu items from the restaurant's menu.

My route is set up as follows

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('menu', function() {
    this.route('add');
  });
});
```

the model functions are working properly but due to the nested route as you add menu items, the menu template grows and grows and pushes the add form way beneath the fold. My question is what is the correct way to get it so that localhost/menu doesn't render when you are on localhost/menu/add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First option**

So it seems that `menu` and `menu.add` routes are not related much.
First suggestion is separating them as they are unrelated routes:

```
  this.route('add-menu');
  this.route('show-menu');
```

**Second option**

But if they are related a bit, one better suggestion is to create a new route to list the menu items. Such as:

```
this.route('menu', function() {
  this.route('add');
  this.route('list');
});
```

By this way, the `menu` route's template will be empty. (In the `menu` route, you may want to add a `redirect` hook to redirect `menu` routes to `menu.list`.)

**Third option**

But I think a far better suggestion is using `index` routes. Instead of defining the `list` route above, use `index` route. The index route will list the menu items.

Have a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f307abb66599227b8ca4b525e4c80dd6?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C).

[Index Routes](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_index-routes) from the Ember Guides.